# Can I use TSQL to query an OLAP database or is MDX required?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm reading a little into data warehouses and OLAP DBs and it's a little unclear if I have to learn MDX to be able to query OLAP databases. Secondly, is SSMS the tool used for querying?

SQL Server 2008 R2 (SSAS 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDX querying in SSAS is done through SSMS. It is not possible to query an Analysis Services instance using TSQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can query SSAS in SQL Server through an OPENROWSET query. Direct data access through SQL queries is not supported, or possible.

Answer (score 0):

Olap queries are quite different than relational SQL.

This book does a great job of explaining MDX:

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12914&locale=en-us